# Confusion about push-notification working with any other way

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I want to know that i don't have IOS Device and not able to receive notification on simulator is there any other way to check push notification without device because i am not able to manage device so can anyone tell me if any other way or not

Comment: no it's not possible without device.

Comment: @Yatendra ok thanks for reply